# How do I generate Excel file with type 'Text' not 'General' by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I'm working on c# project where I'm generating dynamic excel file from my gridview.

when I successfully generate the file it is converting all data into `Genaral` type but I need that all excel file data into `Text` format,

How can I do that? As I need to use this file further for reporting purpose and need `Text` as type

Following is my excel file generation c# code :

```
private void ExportGridView()
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            // Render grid view control.
            gvFiles.RenderControl(htw);

            // Write the rendered content to a file.
            string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\ExportedFile.xls", renderedGridView);
        }
```

[image]

I think I need to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and I can specify Type also like to generate in `Text`

Also I searched like we can generate it as a like html contain and make it excel something like that.

can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, you'll need to have MS Office installed on the machine. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes that is fine for me , can anyone please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Add a reference to it and add the following `using` statement beside the other using statements.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Modify the `ExportGridView` method:

```
private void ExportGridView()
{
    var path = @"C:\test\ExportedFile.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    // Render grid view control.
    gvFiles.RenderControl(htw);

    // Write the rendered content to a file.
    string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
    File.WriteAllText(path, renderedGridView);
    UpdateFormat(path);
}
```

Add the following method:

```
private void UpdateFormat(string path)
{
    var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var doc = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
    for (int i = 1; i <= doc.Worksheets.Count; i++)
    {
        Worksheet sheet = doc.Worksheets[i];
        for (int j = 1; j <= sheet.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Range column = sheet.Columns[j];
            column.NumberFormat = "@";
        }
    }
    doc.Save();
    doc.Close();
    application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: But why it is also generating some `.css`  , `.xml` , `.htm` files too ? 
I dont need those , How can I prevent to generate those?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but its because you're writing the gridview html? You can just create a CSV file and save it with .xls and it'll be an excel document

Comment: I think I need to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and I can specify Type also like to generate in `Text` 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that simply changing the extension of a file from CSV to XLS will generate warnings when opening the file in some versions of Excel, stating that the file is lying about its type. It's not a showstopper but still not very nice.

Comment: @AlexPaven Ah, I haven't ran into that before, but its good to know. thanks!